# Terminal script to create folders and copy files based on part of filename

Tags: terminal, command-line, script

I have a folder with thousands of files in this format

- filenameA - 1.ext
- filenameA - 2.ext
- filenameB - 1.ext

and sometimes

- filenameB - 02.ext

I need a script that will read the files and create a single folder with each distinct filename before the " - #.ext" and then add all files with that same name into the folder.

From the example above I would have two folders 1) filenameA 2) filenameB -
 each with two files in them. The actual data has thousands of files and each group can have 1 to 50ish files, with sequential numbers added to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your files follow the convention of `dirname - the_rest_and_ext` (have the `-` in the middle) you can use something like:

```
for f in *; do
   dir_name=`echo "$f" | sed 's/ -.*//'`
   mkdir -p "$dir_name"
   mv "$f" "$dir_name"
done
```

If all the files have the same extension, you can change the `for` to something like:

```
for f in *.ext; do
```

NOTE: make sure you know what you are doing.

Comment: This works perfectly per my request but you were correct that I do have some filenames with " - " in the title. But none that have " - #" other than number at the end of the file. What do I add to ignore " - " (space-dash-space) when it is not followed by a number?